# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never' in find function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with angular and have cascading selects

```
city: {};
area: {};
selectedAreas: [];
selectedSuburbs: [];
arrAddress = [{
  city: "Auckland",
  id: 1,
  areas: [{
    area: "Waitakere",
    id: 11,
    suburbs: [{
        suburb: "Rodney",
        id: 12
      },
      {
        suburb: "North Shore",
        id: 13
      },
      {
        suburb: "City",
        id: 14
      },
    ]
  }]
}];

onSelectCity(e) {
  this.city = this.arrAddress.find(element => element.id === Number(e.value));
  this.selectedAreas = this.city['areas'];
}

onSelectArea(e) {
  this.area = this.selectedAreas.find(element => element.id === Number(e.value));
  this.selectedSuburbs = this.area['suburbs'];
}
```

In the function `onSelectArea` I am getting an error on `element.id`

> "[ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'."

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some sample data to work with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error you're getting from the compiler is due to `selectedAreas` not being declared properly. By doing `property: []` you define a property that can only hold an empty array.

Use the following instead, which sets the default value (as opposed to the type):

```
selectedAreas = [];  // note the equal sign
```

Or better yet:

```
selectedAreas: Area[] = [];
```

where `Area` would be a class where you define its properties.

You also have the same issue for your other properties (`property: {}` defines a property that can only be an empty object).

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the top of Jeto's answer:

You might want to specify the types of `element` as `any` in the callbacks to the `find` method to avoid any compilation errors:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  city = {};
  area = {};
  selectedAreas: any[] = [];
  selectedSuburbs: any[] = [];
  arrAddress = [...];

  onSelectCity(e) {
    this.city = this.arrAddress.find((element: any) => element.id === Number(e.value));
    this.selectedAreas = this.city['areas'];
  }

  onSelectArea(e) {
    this.area = this.selectedAreas.find((element: any) => element.id === Number(e.value));
    this.selectedSuburbs = this.area['suburbs'];
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<select (change)="onSelectCity($event.target)">
  <option value="null">Select a City</option>
  <option *ngFor="let city of arrAddress" [value]="city.id">{{ city.city }}</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<select (change)="onSelectArea($event.target)" [disabled]="!selectedAreas">
  <option value="null">Select an Area</option>
  <option *ngFor="let area of selectedAreas" [value]="area.id">{{ area.area }}</option>
</select>
```

---

Here's a **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfpgg7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your ref